# swing JMenu retrieve path of a selected item

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

I'm trying to integrate a Jmenu in my java application, but I'm struggled to retrieve the selected path of a selected Item.

I found a couples of examples using the class MenuSelectionManager as follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class selectedPath {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MenuSample Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        // File Menu, F - Mnemonic
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        // File->New, N - Mnemonic
        JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MenuElement[] eles = MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().getSelectedPath();
                System.out.println(eles.length);
                for (MenuElement ele : eles) {
                    System.out.println(ele);
                }
                MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().clearSelectedPath();
            }
        });
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.setSize(350, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

but it didn't work as the MenuElement array is empty. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `MenuSelectionManager` is already cleared when your `actionPerformed` is invoked.

The calls are put in that order:

```
    msm.clearSelectedPath(); // msm is the MenuSelectionManager
    menuItem.doClick(0); // This eventually triggers your actionPerformed
```

But the question is what are you trying to do with that? You obviously know on which `JMenutItem` the click was performed (`e.getSource()` returns the related `JMenuItem`), and you can easily travel back up the component hierarchy to retrieve the complete path of the selected menu, so I wonder what you are trying to achieve with such code.

Comment: Many thanks, I need to know the  entire path of the JMenu clicked to reached the JMenuItem. Could you please tell me how to travel back up the component hierarchy to retrieve the complete path of the selected JMenuItem?

Comment: @RossellaRispoli `((JMenutItem)a.getSource()).getParent();` will give you the parent `JMenu` until you reach the `JMenuBar`